# How do I get the count from ICollection<T> with an unknown T

Tags: c#, .net, collections

Here is my code so far:

```
//TODO: Look for a way of handling ICollection<T>

if (value is ICollection)
{
    return CreateResult(validationContext, ((ICollection)value).Count);
}

if (value is IEnumerable)
{
    var enumerator = ((IEnumerable)value).GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        var count = 0;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            count++;
        return CreateResult(validationContext, count);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (enumerator is IDisposable)
            ((IDisposable)enumerator).Dispose();
    }

}
```

Is there a good way of getting the `Count` out of `ICollection<T>` without resorting to iterating over the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection would be the way to go, but keep in mind that most of the Collections in the FCL inherit from both `ICollection<T>` and `ICollection`  So code like this works:

```
var collection = new List<int>();
Console.WriteLine(collection is ICollection<MyClass>);
Console.WriteLine(collection is ICollection);
```

True is output for both.  This works for most, if not all, collections in the FCL.  If you needed it to work against custom collections, or collections that don't implement ICollection, then reflection is the only way.

Sidenote: Arrays also implicitly implement ICollection, IList and IEnumerable (the CLR actually generates an array that inherits from the generic versions of those classes in addition to the non-generic at runtime), so your above code would work with arrays as well.

Comment: Strange. I looked just before posting this question and I could have sworn that I didn't see a ICollection in the list of interfaces for List<T>. Perhaps I was looking at IList<T> instead.

Comment: This works when 'collection' is a List, but if my type is truly unknown, like a System.Object then it will not work unless a <T> is provided.

Answer (score 6):

Without having the closed type of `ICollection<T>`, you'd have to resort to reflection to call the Count property.

```
if (typeof(ICollection<>) == value.GenericTypeDefinition()) {
  var countProp = value.GetType().GetProperty("Count");
  var count = (int)countProp.GetValue(value, null);
}
```

Comment: Or use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) to do the same thing.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: dynamic is Visual Studio specific, not .NET

Comment: @nic: The article I linked might make it seem that way to someone who isn't intimately familiar with what each version of the language brings, but I assure you - it is a C# 4 feature, not a "visual studio" feature. That said, not sure if it is or isn't available in some form in, say, VB.Net :) But the tags on the question say C#, not just .net

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use reflection:

```
var genCollType = value.GetType()
                       .GetInterfaces()
                       .FirstOrDefault
                           (i => i.IsGenericType 
                              && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));

if (genCollType != null)
{
    int count = (int)genCollType.GetProperty("Count")
                                .GetValue(value, null);

    return CreateResult(validationContext, count);   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Both the ICollection and IEnumerable Interfaces have a property for Count. The generic versions as well.

```
if (value is ICollection)
{
    return CreateResult(validationContext, ((ICollection)value).Count);
}

if (value is IEnumerable)
{
     return CreateResult(validationContext, ((IEnumerable)value).Count);
}
```

MSDN Documentation for ICollection
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx

MSDN Documentation for IEnumerable
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx

Comment: IEnumerable has no property for Count, all it has is an extension method Count().

Comment: I don't even see an extension method for IEnumerable.Count. I do see one for IEnumerable<T>.Count.

Comment: I may have been looking at IEnumerable<T> but Dave has a good point. Why can't you use the extension method?

Comment: You can't use the IEnumerable<T>.Count unless you know what T is at compile time.